# Are there any blocks Endermen can't teleport through?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I'm trying to build a mob zoo but the Enderman keeps escaping. Is there any way I can keep it in? Are there blocks they can't teleport through?

Comment: A mob zoo sounds like a fundamentally flawed concept, hostile mobs despawn.

Comment: @fredley perhaps there is a mod that removes this. What could possibly go wrong ;).

Comment: Ignore the exact duplicate close vote. I apparently need to learn to read.

Comment: @fredley I used to have the despawning problem before, but I fixed it by giving them nametags. I think that if any mob is named, there's a 0% chance of it despawning. However, I've also had a problem with named tropical fish; they still despawn, but no other mobs that I've named do.

Answer (score 13):

Endermen can teleport *through* any type of block if there is ample space on the other side.

What you could do is cover the ground outside with blocks they can not teleport *on top of*. As far as my understanding goes, the only blocks they can't teleport to are **water lava and transparent blocks.** ([Source](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/782807-what-can-enderman-not-teleport-on-top-of)). Alternativly place cobweb on its legs which will completely disable it plus you can do the same with other mobs.Always remember to name them to stop them despawning.

Comment: ok thanks so much that I could use to decorate my zoo as well

Comment: Suggestion: Make your zoo ceiling 2 blocks high and cover the roof with water.

Comment: @fredley - Are you sure they' can't teleport *through* water? And Jesse, if you go this route, you'll need to figure out their teleport range and cover that entire area with water/lava. And make sure there aren't any caves for them to teleport to (I think.

Comment: @fredley They don't teleport 'through' anything, just from and to. The 'to' block must not be lava or water, so by covering the roof with water, and making the inside space too small for them, they have nowhere to go and are trapped.

Comment: is there a limited distance for enderman teleportation? You could fill in everything withing that distance of the enderman except a 2 block high access corridor.

Comment: Actually, making this an undersea facility would be probably easier.

Answer (score 3):

You can just put a sign in the cage, that says "escaped Enderman on the loose, watch out".

Maybe add some humour to the whole thing. I can near guarantee, if there is another cage around the Enderman, he will teleport to it. Enderman are not meant to be contained, be warned!

Answer (score 2):

Endermen can only pick up the following blocks [source](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Enderman#Moving_blocks)

- Grass Block
- Dirt
- Mycelium
- Sand
- Gravel
- Clay
- Dandelion
- Rose
- Brown Mushroom
- Red Mushroom
- Cactus
- Pumpkin
- Melon
- TNT

As long as you make zoo out of something else (like cobblestone, fences, wood etc...) the Endermen should not be able to break your zoo.

Note however the Endermen have the ability to teleport - this is probably why they are escaping.  To my knowledge the Endermen will teleport to *any* available space, regardless of what blocks are between those two points.  The only way I can think of to prevent the Endermen from teleporting would be to invalidate all of the potential teleport destinations within [teleport range](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/49862/how-far-can-an-enderman-move-in-one-teleport) of the zoo, for example by getting rid of any 3-high spaces (Endermen are 3 blocks high and so can only teleport into 3 block high spaces)

Also the Endermen can [despawn](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/21444/when-do-mobs-despawn-in-minecraft), and so could also "escape" that way.

Comment: yes but are there any blocks they cant teleport through?

Comment: @Jesse I don't think so - see my edits

Comment: the question is about teleporting, not about what they can pick up.

Comment: @Philip: A quick look at the edit history shows that the question originally said nothing about teleporting. This was also indicated by the following line in the answer: "Note however the Endermen have the ability to teleport - this is probably why they are escaping."

Answer (score 1):

You can make everythinbg BUT the cage that the endermen is in only 2½ blocks tall, by putting slabs on the roof. Put water on the roof too.

Answer (score 1):

Just dig down deep into the ground. Have ladders on the hole going down. Endermen have a teleporting range of 32 blocks. Make every part of the tunnle 2 blocks high, for the enderman can't teleport to any place that is less then 3 blocks high (as in tunnel size). Make sure the cage is 3 blocks for the enderman to wander around. And don't let any other cage exceed the 2 block high opening.

Answer (score -1):

I think that you can use [Nether Brick](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Nether_Brick). They are black blocks that are crafted from [Netherrack](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Netherrack), which is only found in the Nether. One of my friends tried to trap an Enderman using this material and checked on him a few timesIt appeared that he couldn't teleport out or despawn.

Another you may want to try is [End Stone](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Ender_stone). Minecraft Wiki says that:

> It also cannot be picked up by Endermen and cannot be destroyed by the Enderdragon, and unlike Obsidian, it is easy to mine.

Answer (score -2):

my friend made a endermen trap and they used soul sand so the endermen **couldn't** escape 
I can back it up because I also tried it and it worked

**EDIT:** the endermen Couldn't teleport up because the soul sand was stopping them

Comment: Confirming what your friend said for your *personal* knowledge is not the same as confirming it for the Internet's knowledge. For that you need to provide screenshots of the setup, how long the Enderman has been trapped, whether they stay trapped even if you pour water on them, etc. Just saying "It works! I have proof that I'm not bothering to show you!" doesn't actually work.

Comment: I can't insert pictures because I don't have any

Comment: @SevenSidedDie The proof is in another similar question. An answer to the question included this sentence: "Endermen do not teleport in the daytime when on soul sand unless damaged"

Comment: @mademy1stserverplshelp Again, proof elsewhere is not providing proof here. It’s a request to fix the answer, not saying it’s untrue.

Comment: You could test it out if you want to. I'm not saying that to be rude, I want to know too. I just can't because I'm having my own problems with Minecraft, namely it's not launching right now.