# How do I prevent Endermen from teleporting?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

Can Endermen teleport out of a cage made of border blocks in minecraft pocket edition? If not is there a way to disable mob teleportation?

[image: Border block]

Answer (score 1):

It depends. It is possible to build a cage out of corner blocks if you fulfill the requirements outlined below:

From [the wiki:](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Enderman)

> Each (teleportation) attempt chooses a random destination 32 blocks
> along each axis (i.e. a 64×64×64 cuboid centered on the current
> position). It then seeks downward, regardless of distance, from the
> chosen destination until the block below is made of a
> movement-blocking material.

> The teleportation attempt succeeds if no
> liquid or solid blocks prevent them from standing at the destination.
> Thus, endermen need at least three non-solid blocks above the
> destination to successfully teleport, with a few exceptions, such as a
> carpet that is not above a block made of a movement-blocking material,
> lily pads, and snow layers stacked 10 blocks deep or more, as their
> materials are not flagged as blocking movement even though the blocks
> themselves do so.

Additionally, Endermen do not teleport to waterlogged blocks. Endermen do not teleport in the daytime if on soul sand unless they are damaged.

Simply encapsulating an Endermen in corner blocks will not necessarily prevent teleportation.

**EDIT:**
See [this old answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/86377/are-there-any-blocks-endermen-cant-teleport-through) for more information. While it's about Java edition, it applies to Bedrock as well.

Comment: Hmm..... If there was a command or something like that to disable this it would be preferred as I don't want to create such a huge area of slabs/carpets/liquids.I also don't want to use boats to trap them. Downwards direction is not a problem as it is a flat world.